# C++ inheritance and abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Interface`. An interface has a `read` method that reads the data and parses it, and a `getData` method that actually returns the parsed data. Each interface has a `Parser` object that does the actual parsing. A Parser has a `parse` method and getters for the parsed data.
The classes `USBInterface` and `SerialInterface` inherit from `Interface`.

The problem:
How can I use a different parser for `USBInterface` and `SerialInterface`?
There are two parsers, `USBParser` and `SerialParser`, that inherit from `Parser`.

My current solution uses a `Parser` reference in the `Interface` base class that's initialized in the Interface constructor, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

```
 class Parser {
  public:
    Parser() {}
    int getData() {
      return data;
    }
  protected:
    int data;
};

class USBParser : public Parser {
  public:
    USBParser() {}
    bool parse(uint8_t *usbpacket) {
      data = usbpacket[1]; // Do the actual parsing here
      return true; // Return true if data is complete
    }
};

class SerialParser : public Parser {
  public:
    SerialParser() {}
    bool parse(uint8_t databyte) {
      data = databyte; // Do the actual parsing here
      return true; // Return true if data is complete
    }
};

class Interface {
  public:
    Interface(Parser &parser) : parser(parser) {}
    virtual bool read() = 0;
    int getData() {
      return parser.getData();
    }
  protected:
    Parser &parser;
};

class USBInterface : public Interface {
  public:
    USBInterface() : Interface(parser) {}
    bool read() {
      uint8_t usbpacket[4] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}; // Read raw data from USB
      return parser.parse(usbpacket);
    }
  private:
    USBParser parser;
};

class SerialInterface : public Interface {
  public:
    SerialInterface() : Interface(parser) {}
    bool read() {
      uint8_t databyte = 0xFF; // Read raw data from serial port
      return parser.parse(databyte);
    }
  private:
    SerialParser parser;
};

int main() {
  USBInterface usb;
  SerialInterface serial;

  if (usb.read())
    println(usb.getData());
  if (serial.read())
    println(serial.getData());
}
```

Are there any flaws in my approach, or is there a better way?

Comment: The question is opinion based. your approach will work The only flaw is that your example does not need any inheritance. Your code just looks over-complicated with no reason behind it, except a desire to add inheritance.

Comment: @Serge: thank you for your comment. The code I posted is simplified. The goal of the inheritance is to make abstraction of the type of interface. The rest of the program shouldn't care if a USB interface or a Serial interface is used, it just has to be able to read data from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks bit over-complicated to me. Instead you can use dependency injection as class `USBInterface` depends on `USBParser` like wise `SerialInterface` depends on `SerialParser`. It gives you more flexibility. In case you have something like `GenericParser` that you want to use with `USBInterface` or `SerialInterface`.

```
class Parser {
  public:
    Parser() {}
    int getData() {
      return data;
    }
  protected:
    int data;
};

class USBParser : public Parser {
  public:
    USBParser() {}
    bool parse(uint8_t *usbpacket) {
      data = usbpacket[1]; // Do the actual parsing here
      return true; // Return true if data is complete
    }
};

class SerialParser : public Parser {
  public:
    SerialParser() {}
    bool parse(uint8_t databyte) {
      data = databyte; // Do the actual parsing here
      return true; // Return true if data is complete
    }
};

class Interface {
  public:
    Interface(Parser &parser) : parser(parser) {}
    virtual bool read() = 0;
    int getData() {
      return parser.getData();
    }
  protected:
    Parser &parser;
};

class USBInterface : public Interface {
  public:
    USBInterface(Parser &parser) : Interface(parser) {}
    bool read() {
      uint8_t usbpacket[4] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}; // Read raw data from USB
      return parser.parse(usbpacket);
    }
};

class SerialInterface : public Interface {
  public:
    SerialInterface(Parser &parser) : Interface(parser) {}
    bool read() {
      uint8_t databyte = 0xFF; // Read raw data from serial port
      return parser.parse(databyte);
    }
};

int main() {
  USBParser usbParse
  USBInterface usb(usbParse);

  SerialParse serialParse;
  SerialInterface serial(serialParse);

  // GenericParse parse;
  // SerialInterface serial(parse);

  if (usb.read())
    println(usb.getData());
  if (serial.read())
    println(serial.getData());
}
```

Comment: I see two immediate problems with this approach: `USBParser::parse` takes a pointer to an array of bytes, while `SerialParser::parse` takes a single byte. On top of that, dependency injection doesn't make it simpler: A USB Interface _always_ uses a USB Parser, so there is no need to rely on the user to supply the right Parser to the Interface.